# Does Perl have arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl

I am new to Perl and want to know if there is any data structure consisting of a collection of elements. I'm familiar with MATLAB, which has arrays with elements that are identified by indices. Does Perl also have arrays?

For example, in Perl, how would I gather and store a collection of file names for files that all have the same extension?

Comment: Re "I woud say in MATLAB we could do it by a array", I don't understand what "it" want you want do, but Perl has arrays too.

Comment: Perl has two fundamental data structures for collections: arrays and hashes (which are associative arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very straight forward in Perl. Here, we use a glob to collect the names of all .txt files in the current working directory, and save them into an array. We then loop over the array and print the name of each file. The `use warnings;` and `use strict;` lines should always be included at the top of the script to prevent common issues.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = <*.txt>;

for my $file (@array){
    print "$file\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to print just a specific entry of `@array`?